# VB6.exe gets stuck when running in non-interactive mode via a TFS release pipeline

Tags: powershell, tfs, vb6

I have a Powershell script that is designed to compile VB6 projects on build servers. It calls VB6.exe with the correct arguments. When I run the PS script on the local machine, the script works beautifully. However, when invoking the script via a TFS release pipeline with the same arguments, VB6.exe hangs forever. I can see the vb6.exe process running in Task Manager but it just hangs there forever. This is essentially the exact same problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615794/compile-vb6-as-background-process-on-server-2016/71800338#71800338) but there was no answer there.

I know it is not a permissions problem, as the PS script uses -Verb runAs and logs into the machine as the same user that I am logged in to when running the script interactively.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? I am wondering if it is registry related but do not have enough information to say that for sure.

Comment: Do you have usercontrols like in the answer on the other Q?  If you try to compile a totally minimal project, does it still fail?

Comment: Hey StayOnTarget, none of the projects I am compiling have user controls, they are all backend projects. Also, I did try compiling a simple Hello World project without any user controls and got the same issue.

Comment: Maybe add the details of the hello world project to the question just in case someone notices anything, but that does make it seem like its not project related.

Comment: I wonder if you deliberately add a syntax error so it can't compile, what happens?

Comment: Another suggestion is to track VB6.exe using process monitor and see what happens before/when it freezes up. That might yield an important clue.

Comment: Just in case you haven't seen it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744887/vb6-freezes-when-making-exe-file

Comment: There is also this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082752/jenkins-vb6-build-failures

Comment: Have you tried a batch file instead of PS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/batch-script?view=azure-devops